Access Text box value from User control to another User control in VB6
I have a requirement in VB6 to access the value of textbox from one User Controls user1.ctl in another User controls user2.ctl of the same project, and if the textbox value > 100, need to set it 100. I have not worked on such things till now in Visual basic, your help is appreciated.

The textbox will not be accessible outside of the user control so you will need to expose the textbox by adding public properties to your user control:
Public Property Get SomeTextBox() As String
   SomeTextBox = Text1.Text
End Property

Public Property Let SomeTextBox(ByVal Value As String)
   Text1.Text = Value
End Property

If you drop that user control onto a form then from that form you will say:
If user1.SomeTextBox > 100 Then
   user1.SomeTextBox = 100
End If

If you drop a second user control onto the form and want to update the first user control from the second user control then from the second user control you will say:
If UserControl.Parent.user1.SomeTextBox > 100 Then
   UserControl.Parent.user1.SomeTextBox = 100
End If


I started getting this error "Object Variable or with block variable not set"   My Code: UserControl.parent.ctlDs01.amtDischargeFees.

Is this code inside a user control?  If so, make sure ctlDs01 is a valid user control and that anything you are doing inside the property is using valid (not Nothing) objects.
